# Umbraco: 'Encountered end tag "html" with no matching start tag. Are your start/end tags properly balanced?'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

Using Umbraco and have set up a page template and created a page in the Content section. However when I try to view the page I have created, I am getting the following error:

"Encountered end tag "html" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?"

Even though the code has opening and closing html tags.

If I remove both html tags, I get the same error but for the  tags. If I remove them it changes to  tags and so on...

Anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the top of the template you have created and make sure its the first tag on your page. Make sure you haven't included the opening tag inside an if statement and make sure the opening and closing html tags are in the very top template not in the templates inheriting from the master.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code this is a tricky one to answer.  The most obvious answer is that you are inheriting templates & you've got an additional start or close html tag somewhere in the inheritance.

**EDIT**
You could now put your html tags back in & change your template (in the umbraco back office) so that doesn't inherit from anything & see if the template alone works - if so your template inheritance is wrong.

Umbraco 6 template that doesn't inherit:
[image]

Umbraco 4 template that doesn't inherit:
[image]

Comment: Thought this but if I remove both html tags, I get the same error but for the <body> tags. If I remove them it changes to <div> tags and so on...

Comment: Well its a start!  You could now put your html tags back in & change your template (in the umbraco back office) so that doesn't inherit from anything.  I'll add a couple of images to this answer.